# How to Disable Linux kernel tracer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit). The current tracer is set as nop.

```
cat current_tracer 
nop

cat tracing_on 
0
```

**Although the current tracer is nop and tracing is disabled**, all these following messages are printing and continuously printed while I am performing other operations. **Why is this so happening ? How can I disable to print these messages being printed?**

```
<...>-573   [003] ....     6.304043: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf" 0 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304055: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf" 0 666
               <...>-569   [000] ....     6.304073: do_sys_open: "/run/udev/data/c4:73" 88000 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304077: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf" 0 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304087: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf" 0 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304119: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf" 0 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304135: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-watchdog.conf" 0 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304166: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" 0 666
               <...>-569   [000] ....     6.304180: do_sys_open: "/run/udev/data/c4:73.tmp" 88241 666
               <...>-573   [003] ....     6.304190: do_sys_open: "/etc/modprobe.d/vmwgfx-fbdev.conf" 0 666
```

Any link or explanation will be a great help. Thank you in advance.